# Chrome API not injecting cookies in nested callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cookies

I am building an application that needs to inject cookies into google chrome via an extension. The problem I am having seems to be an fault in my understanding of javascript callbacks. I have the following..

edited: simpler example that doesn't work still.

```
    $scope.selectAccount = function(account)
    {
        $scope.account = account;
        setProxy(account.proxy.ip,account.proxy.port);
        armProxyAuth(account.proxy);
        chrome.windows.create({"url": "http://facebook.com", "incognito": true},function(window){
            chrome.cookies.getAllCookieStores(function(stores){
                bg.console.log('echo stores?');
                bg.console.log(stores);
                for(var i =0;i<stores.length;i++){
                    bg.console.log(stores[i].tabIds);
                    bg.console.log(window.tabs[0].id);
                    if(stores[i].tabIds[0]==window.tabs[0].id)
                    {
                        chrome.cookies.set({
                            "name": "xs", //secure, http only
                            "url":"https://www.facebook.com",
                            "httpOnly": true,
                            "domain":"www.facebook.com",
                            "secure": true,
                            "value": account.cookies.xs
                        },function (cookie) {
                            bg.console.log('cookie set');
                            bg.console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
                        });
                        chrome.cookies.set({
                            "name": "c_user", //secure
                            "url":"https://www.facebook.com",
                            "secure": true,
                            "httpOnly": false,
                            "value": account.cookies.c_user
                        },function (cookie) {
                            bg.console.log('cookie 2 set');
                            bg.console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

This does everything I expect except for the actual addCookies part, the cookies are never added, no errors are thrown. I also find that sometimes the chrome.cookies.getAllCookieStores callback is never fired either, it is incredibly inconsistent in what is executed and I can't seem to trace any rhyme or reason to it.

When I do the following

```
 $scope.selectAccount = function(account)
 {
        $scope.account = account;
        addCookies(account.cookies);
 }
```

The cookies are loaded up no problem. I am not sure if there is a breakdown in my javascript, or the chrome API, or something else is going on. If anyone could shine some light on it that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

When a function is called from another function using a true "callback", such as in `setTimeout`, or `$.ajax()`, the function is called without parameters and its scope is the largest scope of the environment, usually the `window` object (with a few exceptions).

You can't pass in `account.cookies` into `addCookies`, since  the `function(window){` on *line 6* is a callback function and loses the `account` variable in its scope.

Even further, when you have `function(stores){` as a callback to `chrome.cookies.getAllCookieStores(`, you once again reset the scope of the internal function to one where there is no `account` variable.

Therefore, `account.cookies`, when passed into `addCookies` is equivalent to just calling `addCookies` by itself, since `account.cookies` and `account` itself are `undefined` in the scope in which you are calling `addCookies`.

Comment: In that case, what is the correct way to execute this? Since chrome.cookies.set needs data from chrome.cookies.getAllCookies how does one set this up correctly?

Comment: Try looking at [this article](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/extra-data.html). I've tried out most of these solutions and they mostly work, but may need to be slightly modified to accommodate different scenarios.